# Github : how to access public repository anonymously?

Tags: github, repository, anonymous

I'd like to download anonymously public repositories source code in my computer using java. So, I know how to download source code in repository using kohsuke-git-api. but, I didn't find how to access public repositories anonymously.
(repositories are not mine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All github repositories can be accessed directly, unauthenticated, anonymously via http:

```
git clone http://github.com/user/reponame
```

Comment: I know this way. However, first I don't know username and repository name.

Comment: @Rect: You're not making sense; if you don't know the owner of the repository nor its name, you don't know what you want to clone.

I think you should really really bring an example of what you want to do in your question.

Answer (score -3):

Amm just use a VPN to make your browser anonymous and download away I guess:
http://hackerbot.net/tutorials/356-use-internet-anonymously

Its really not that difficult. Acutally even a free proxy might do it.

Comment: You don't need a VPN to clone a git repo from Git Hub anonymously, you can just clone via HTTP